# Como pegar o número do índice de um array?

Tags: php, array

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
Array
(
    [CPF_CNPJ] => Array
    (
    )
    [TIPO] => Array
    (
    )
    [NOME] => Array
    (
    )
)
```

Sei que `key(array)` me retorna o NOME da chave atual em um loop, mas gostaria de pegar o índice da  chave e não o nome.

Exemplo

```
[CPF_CNPJ] = 0
[TIPO] = 1
[NOME] = 2
```

Vou ter que fazer um `foreach` pra isso?

Não vi no manual do PHP uma função própria pra isso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para isso, se percebi bem, pode usar [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
$arr = array(
   'CPF_CNPJ' => array(),
   'TIPO' => array(),
   'Nome' => array(),
);

$arr = array_keys($arr);
```

Output de `$arr`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => CPF_CNPJ
    [1] => TIPO
    [2] => Nome
)
```

Para [saber a key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) de um dado valor (chave do array original) deste novo array:

```
array_search('TIPO', $arr); // 1
```

Resumindo, ex: para saber o index numérico da chave `'Nome'`:

```
echo array_search("Nome", array_keys($arr)); // chave 2
```

Comment: hum, cheguei a ver essa função, realmente ela numera os indices, mas na verdade eu queria pegar o numero indice sem ter que estender muito a rotina, seria tipo assim: **$indice = $meuarray["CPF_CNPJ"].ItemIndex**, no Delphi por exemplo podemos fazer **Numero = MinhaLista("campo").ItemIndex;**

Comment: @Marcelo, exato estou a perceber, mas que eu saiba e pelo que vi agora que me disse isso: https://www.google.pt/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=get+numeric+index+of+assciative+array&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=OfihV-_jFuas8weX3JOQDg#channel=fs&q=get+numeric+index+of+assciative+array+php, parece fazer tudo uso destas funções, creio que em php a maneira melhor é assim e não há volta a dar

Comment: @Marcelo É só fazer assim: `$indice = array_search('CPF_CNPJ', array_keys($meuArray));`

Comment: Exato tal como o @zekk disse e como está no final da resposta também não passa de uma linha

Comment: Realmente é isso mesmo, desatenção da minha parte.

Comment: Não faz mal @Marcelo. ainda bem que resolveu